# props.onChange(e.target.value) returns an object instead of a value in textField in material ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

```
  function FormInput(props) {
    const classes = formInputStyles();
    return (
      <div>
        <TextField
        onChange={(e) => props.onChange(e.target.value)}
          InputProps={{ classes, disableUnderline: true }}
          {...props}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

when trying to pass (e.target.value) to the component it returns a object

**Object { _reactName: "onChange", _targetInst: null, type: "change", nativeEvent: input, target: input.MuiInputBase-input.MuiFilledInput-input, currentTarget: input.MuiInputBase-input.MuiFilledInput-input, eventPhase: 3, bubbles: true, cancelable: false, timeStamp: 1398131, … }**

```
<FormInput
    onChange={(value) => {
    console.log(value);
    }}
    label="Username"
    variant="filled"
></FormInput>
```

but when i try to alert the value it says "**[object Object]**"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `onChange` props in the `TextField` is overridden by the `props.onChange`. This:

```
<TextField
  onChange={(e) => props.onChange(e.target.value)}
  InputProps={{ classes, disableUnderline: true }}
  {...props}
/>
```

Can be translated to:

```
<TextField
  onChange={(e) => props.onChange(e.target.value)}
  InputProps={{ classes, disableUnderline: true }}
  {...}
  // because you're spreading all props. props.onChange receives e (object)
  // instead of e.target.value
  onChange={props.onChange}
/>
```

The solution is to extract the `onChange` props and spread the rest like below:

```
function FormInput({ onChange, ...rest }) {
  const classes = formInputStyles();

  return (
    <div>
       <TextField
         onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.value)}
         InputProps={{ classes, disableUnderline: true }}
         {...rest}
       />
    </div>
  );
}
```